# Select Case conversion not displaying properly, how can i fix?

Tags: vb.net, select-case

I have an executable that when run takes an inputted date and then selects what date suffix is needed with it, however it is always defaulting to the case else.

when i have 02/04/2017 as format DD/MM/YYYY the result of the below case is 2th April instead of 2nd...

Could anyone enlighten me on the problem.

```
    Dim Datewc As Date = Nothing

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Datewc = TextBox1.Text
    End If

    'Determine date suffix
    Dim datsuff As String = ""

    Select Case CInt(Datewc.Day)
        Case 1 Or 21 Or 31
            datsuff = "st"
        Case 2 Or 22
            datsuff = "nd"
        Case 3 Or 23
            datsuff = "rd"
        Case Else
            datsuff = "th"
    End Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse you date

```
Dim dDate As DateTime = 
  DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Change your code a little, should work.
[Day](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b4h8sxy(v=vs.90).aspx) function returns integer, no need to Cast using CInt.

```
 'Determine date suffix
Dim datsuff As String = ""

Select Case Datewc.Day
    Case 1 , 21 , 31
        datsuff = "st"
    Case 2 , 22
        datsuff = "nd"
    Case 3 , 23
        datsuff = "rd"
    Case Else
        datsuff = "th"
End Select
```

**Explanation**

`Case 2 Or 22` means `Case ((2 Or 22) ==true)`, It will be false hence going to else part.